# How can to determine excel files's name that be have error while reading by pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have many Excel files (about 500 files). The Excel files have different sheets. The purpose of the written code is to extract data from specific columns and rows in the second sheet. The output of the desired code is the collection of extracted data in Excel file format named 'FluidsVolumeReport.xlsx'.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

filenames = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
dlist = []
for file in filenames:
    Dict = {}
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    Sheet_Names_list = xl.sheet_names
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name= Sheet_Names_list[1])
    for row in range(3, 8):
        Dict.update({"Date": df.iat[2, 2]})
        Dict.update({df.iat[9, 25]: df.iat[9, 35]})
        Dict.update({df.iat[10, 25]: df.iat[10, 35]})
        Dict.update({df.iat[row, 40]: df.iat[row, 47]})
    dlist.append(Dict)
dflist = []
for i in range(0, len(dlist)):
    Dict = dlist[i]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=Dict, index=[0])
    dflist.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dflist, axis=0, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
df.replace(0.0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df.to_excel('FluidsVolumeReport.xlsx')
```

The code has error while reading some Excel files due to the file not opening or not matching the specified range, and as a result the code stops giving an error.

**IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14**

My aim is to write a code that ignores any Excel files that have errors and reports the names of these files. Please help me complete my code.

Comment: Have you looked at `try-except`?

Comment: @rahlf23 thnks so much. i know try-except, but can you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @rahlf23, you could do something like that (to keep it simple):

```
...
try:
    for file in filenames:
        ...
        dlist.append(Dict)
except IndexError:
    print(file)
    pass
dflist = []
...
```